# Combine GitLab Pages from different projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to combine pages created from different GitLab projects in a single site. I could do this in the following way:

- Updates to project `foo` triggers a build of project `pages-builder`.
- Updates to project `bar` triggers a build of project `pages-builder`.
- Project `pages-builder` has a `.gitlab-ci.yml` that:

  - Clones and builds project `foo`
  - Clones and builds project `bar`
  - Puts everything relevant in the `public` directory and deploys the pages.

In order for `pages-builder` to be able to clone `foo` and `bar`, I use SSH keys and deploy keys, as explained [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html).

This works, but it means building both `foo` and `bar` whenever any of them is updated, and I would like to build only the one that triggers the build. With trigger variables I can probably build only what is needed, but then the project that was not built disappears from the deployed pages. I guess I would have to somehow restore previous artifacts, but the only way I found to do this requires using my private token in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file (or in the project's variables), which I'm reluctant to do. Any ideas?